# ref code with link in html document

Tags: html, web-traffic, click-through

So for tracking purposes my company wants to put a ref code on each link that's clicked. So if I had a a ref code of ref=talkawalk12 and had to implement it to any kind of link how do I format that?

Comment: Could you show what you have tried so far?

Comment: http:www.habitatlife.com/?utm_source=partneremail&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=‌​partnerjjj5email&ref=talkawalk12 so before the link didnt have the "&ref=talkawalk12" at the end. Is adding that the correct way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually you have links in anchor tags, and the location of the link is defined in the 'href' attribute of the tag. If I am understanding your question right, you are looking to do something like:

```
<a href="your_company_link?ref=talkawalk12">Link Text Here</a>
```

If you are redirecting buttons or other tags in an onClick, then you would need to substitute the redirect location with what is inside the 'href' attribute.

Comment: so if i had a link like http:www.habitatlife.com/?utm_source=partneremail&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=partnersj3email i would just add an & and then the ref code? so http:www.habitatlife.com/?utm_source=partneremail&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=partnerjjj5email&ref=talkawalk12 ?

Comment: It would depend on how habitatlife.com received the ref code and where. For example, is the 'ref' parameter something specific to the homepage?  Or maybe another page, like: www.habitatlife.com/another_page?ref=talkawalk12. If it can be received at any resource identifier with the host domain www.habitatlife.com, then the above should work. Give it a shot with one link and see if it works how you expect it to.

Comment: We have an email going out and they want to use that code for our main link and also the link for our video so they are too different links.